# photoshop's "file info" dialog takes a long time to open

Tags: windows-xp, adobe-photoshop, metadata, jpeg, psd

I needed to edit some of the metadata that gets saved with images.The images in question were pulled from a camera and are 2576x1932 @ 230dpi, and saved as PSDs. In Photoshop CS4, if I open the PSDs and go to File > File Info, it takes approximately 2-3 minutes before it displays the dialog window. In the meantime, photoshop freezes and jumps to 25% CPU utilization. That seems like an excessively long time, considering my hardware specs are decent (Win XP 32-bit, Q9550, 4GB RAM seen as 3.25GB). Any other actions, such as opening, saving and editing take under a second.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried it in Bridge?

Comment: Could you please post one such image so I could have a look. Include @harrymc in a comment when it is available.

Comment: @Daniel I don't use bridge, but I gave it a whirl and that function seemed to operate quickly (loading bridge, however, took quite a while). @harrymc here's an example file: http://forceflow.50webs.com/100_0916.zip

Comment: Some thing is wrong with your link, the file seems to be truncated to 129 bytes.

Comment: As it turns out, that hosting service now has a file size limit where it didn't before. I uploaded elsewhere: http://www.mediafire.com/?ebdwsuezl0dy5v0

Comment: Mediafire refuses to work without cookies, so no way I'll give it free access to my browser. In any case, I see the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebooting, clearing out all my temp files, running windows updates, and running adobe updates, it looks like the problem fixed itself. Opening the file info dialog now takes about 1 second to open.